# Some program to change the bpm of a track?

Tags: sound, 18.04, sound-editor

Someone knows some program in Ubuntu to change the bpm of a track, retaining the tone. I've tried with Audacity, but when changing the bpm, it also changes the tone. Any idea? Maybe whit LMMS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can in Audacity.

Referring from [the manual](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/change_tempo.html), you can access it by **Effect** > **Change Tempo**.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

*Playback* changes (rather than permanent changes to the track itself) can be accomplished quite easily using the command line MPlayer and the 'scaletempo' filter. Typical syntax is (halving the playback speed in this case):

```
mplayer -af scaletempo -speed 0.5 input.mp4
```

From here playback speed can be adjusted *during playback* using the default '{' and '}' keys. This filter is unfortunately not available in the best gui for MPlayer: SMPlayer.

*Permanent* changes to a track's speed can be accomplished with the use of FFmpeg: using the '[setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts)' video filter and the '[atempo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atempo)' audio filter. The following syntax *doubles* both audio and video speed *without altering pitch*:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" \
output.mp4
```

And increments are possible for both speeding up and slowing down a track...

**References:**

- [Top 10 Tricks and Tips for the svn MPlayer](http://www.andrews-corner.org/linux/topten.html) My own page :). Have a look at Tip 1: Using 'scaletempo'...
- [How to speed up / slow down a video](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video) Solid information on the subject from the FFmpeg Trac site...